# Is there a standard name for functions whose fibers are finite on every element in their image?

Tags: functions, terminology, covering-spaces

What would you call a function $f$ with the property that $\forall y\in \text{img}(f)\left(\left|f^{-1}[\{y\}]\right|\in \mathbb{N}\right)$?

What about a function whose fibers all have the same cardinality?

Do either of these have a standard name? I'm trying to formalize a certain kind of map between objects, that should satisfy this and I don't want to make up notation if possible. It sorta reminds me of covering maps between topological spaces, though I can't think of the right word for this.

Comment: If all the fibres are of the same cardinality $n$, then the map is $n$-to-one, though that is a definition I would clarify explicitly before using for the first time.

Comment: I've seen "finite-to-one" used, but I don't know if that's standard.

Comment: Thanks those both the terms "finite-to-one" and "$n$-to-one" seem to show up in multiple articles online e.g. https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Finite-to-one_mapping

Comment: If you give the domain and codomain the discrete topology, then this is equivalent to $f$ being proper (meaning $f^{-1}$ of any compact subset is compact).  That said, I'd probably go with "finite-to-one" as well.